# Eslint detects formatting errors, but does not fix them at save (Vue/cli 4.2) despite 'lintOnSave: true'

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

I have recently created a project with Vue/cli 4.2. The problem is that Eslint detects formatting errors (eg. double quotation marks in script, no space between function parentheses), but does not fix them at save despite explicit `lintOnSave: true` in `vue.config.js`. It is supposed to be default value, but if I don’t state this setting, eslint will break compilation and throw formatting errors. If I include `lintOnSave: true`, compilation is performed and errors are just marked in code and listed in terminal. The only errors that are fixed are trailing spaces, but that probably results from `.editorconfig` settings.

I am working on VS Code. I have the “formatOnSave” option disabled (otherwise VS Code applies it’s own settings). I don’t think it’s a fault of VS Code settings, because if I work on some older projects created with vue-cli 3.7 – they work fine and autoformat is performed correctly. I have compared the settings and they are basically the same (except for `lintOnSave: true` which is not necessary in the older version).

How can I fix this?

Here are my settings – they might be a bit messy, as I performed a lot of trial-and-error:

1) *** .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    es6: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    '@vue/standard'
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    indent: ['error', 4],
    semi: ["error", "always"],
    "space-before-function-paren": ["error", "always"],
    quotes: ["error", "single"]
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaVersion: 6
  }
}
```

2) *** vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: true, // If I remove this line, Eslint will break compilation and throw formatting errors
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
      config
          .plugin('html')
          .tap(args => {
              args[0].title = 'App title';
              return args;
          });
      config.resolve.alias
          .set('@comp', path.resolve('src/components/'));
  }
};
```

3) *** .editorconfig

```
[*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```

4) *** package.json

```
{
  "name": "turniejomat",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk": "^4.8.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "portal-vue": "^2.1.6",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-bootstrap-vue": "~0.6.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

I'll appreciate any hints how to fix the lack of auto formatting.

Comment: have you found any solution if yes please let us know

Comment: @EaBengaluru Don't remember exactly, but I think I just configured eslint in VS Code and disabled the buggy Vue linting...